# Handle script in webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

This is a webservice having script loaded on CheckJs webmethod.

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string CheckJs()
    {
        string script = "<script> (function() { alert('script loaded'); })(); </script>";

        return script;
    }
```

Checkscript.js

Here we call the AJAX method to consume webservice result

```
function Loadarticlecomments() {
inputdata = {};        
var outputhtml = "";
var newurl = "/WebServices/CheckJsScript/WSScript.asmx/CheckJs";
var dataStrVal = "";

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: newurl,
    data: dataStrVal,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {            
        if (result.d != null && result.d.length > 0) {                
            $(".commentsid").html((result.d));
        }
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log('JS Script-  system failure');
        return false;
    }

});
```

}

script is not firing.Could you please someone fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The script is not firing when you insert it in page because there is *no one* to execute it, is just standing there.

You can make use of `eval()` to execute an javascrip code represented as string. Don't forget to **remove** `<script>` tags from service.

```
// code
success: function(result) {            
    if (result.d != null && result.d.length > 0) {                
        eval(result.d); // execute script returned by service
    }
},
// other code
```

**Note:** Consider reading this, before use it, [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

```js
var data = "(function() { alert('script loaded'); })()"
eval(data);
```